# Cron Job issu with rails - gem whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cron, cron-task

I am trying to do a simple Cron task using the gem whenever for rails.

How can I tell whenever to trigger a controller action ?

What I wan to do :

```
every 1.minute do
    runner "Mycontroller.index", :environment => 'development'
end
```

What i want to do is to trigger the action index in my DataController every minute. The index action trigger a mailer.

I run : whenever --update-crontab football

also when I start/restart my server I get a tinny message as follow:

You have new mail in /var/mail/Antoine

> [2015-04-12 18:38:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 [2015-04-12 18:38:17] INFO
>
> ruby 2.1.3 (2014-09-19) [x86_64-darwin14.0] [2015-04-12 18:38:17] INFO
>
> WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22476 port=3000 ^C[2015-04-12 18:38:52]
>
> INFO  going to shutdown ... [2015-04-12 18:38:52] INFO
>
> WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done. Exiting 
>   You have new mail in
>   /var/mail/Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
    command "curl http://localhost:3000", :environment => 'development'
end
```

I use the command curl to got to the route where I wish to trigger a controller action.

I also understood that I need to run `whenever -w` to write the cron task and then I can do `crontab -l` to see my ongoing cron tasks and if I wan to remove cron taks I just need to run `crontab -r`